# countplot in seaborn of python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have CSV data from titanic machine learning for disaster website:

https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data

CSV files named train and test are available.

train.csv has the column 'Survived'. I need to do a countplot for this column and give 'hue' arguments as below:

```
sns.countplot(x='Survived', data=train, hue='Sex', hue='Pclass')
```

Here I could add only one option for hue. Is there any possibility to add more options to hue argument. If so, How can I add

Comment: if the solution works for you, consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

You can use [seaborn.catplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html). You can try this code,

```
sns.catplot(x="Survived", hue="Sex", col="Pclass",
                data=train, kind="count",
                height=4, aspect=.9);
```